# Solr search: Search name by alphabets

Tags: solr

Is there a way to do a solr search by alphabets like:
in the query i want to search all names starting with alphabet 'A'.
Please help me on this.
Thanks,
GK

Comment: just make sure `name` is of type string and not a text field. Otherwise `Jessica Alba` may match `name:A*` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can specify in the query something like this :

```
name:A*
```

(Where `name` is you field name)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the whole documents or just values from particular field? For full documents just use (as in the other answer) field:prefix*

If you want just the list of terms in specific field, you can use [TermComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) (with terms.prefix).